# .htaccess RewriteRule to path without changing URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I've this problem:

1. Base Website located at `http://example.com/`
2. Second Website located at `http://example.com/web2/`
3. People making various requests to the second website like
   `http://example.com/myWeb/pg1` and `http://example.com/web2/pg2`

Recently and due to some other issues I need to have a custom new path for the second website but also keep the first one working.

The ideia is to allow users to access the second website over the two following addresses:

- `http://example.com/web2/`
- `http://example.com/alternative-url-web2/`

The folder `/web2/` actually exists on the server, but how can I simulate the folder `/alternative-url-web2/` and "redirect" the requests to `/web2/`?

Please note I don't want the URL on the browser to change, this must be a "silent redirect". And I also make sure that all other requests like `http://example.com/other` are not redirected by the second website.

Thank you.

---

**Update**:

According to @anubhava I could simply solve this issue by adding in my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^alternative-url-web2(/.*|)$ /web2$1 [L,NC]
```

This is probably working fine but I noticed the following:

- `http://ex.com/alternative-url-web2` is redirected to `http://ex.com/web2/` (changing browser URL);
- `http://ex.com/alternative-url-web2/` is redirected to `http://ex.com/`(changing browser URL);
- `http://ex.com/alternative-url-web2/someRequest` works fine and does NOT change the browser URL;
- `http://ex.com/alternative-url-web2/index.php` works fine and does NOT change the browser URL;

**Site Note:**

At `/web2/` there's an `.htaccess` that *might* be cause the wired redirect behavior above... So here is the file contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can the internal RewriteRule to `index.php` be causing all this? If yes, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^alternative-url-web2(/.*|)$ /web2$1 [L,NC]
```

**Alternate code:**

```
RewriteRule ^alternative-url-web2/?$ /web2/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^alternative-url-web2/(.+)$ /web2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Alternate code works for me partially... Just HTML is loading correctly. CSS and JS missing... Any idea?

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty simple rewrite. In the htaccess file in your document root, just add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^alternative-url-web2/?(.*)$ /web2/$1 [L]
```

Unlike a redirect, which makes the browser/client send a new request for a new URL (thus changing what's in the browser's location bar), a rewrite happens entirely on the server's side.

Comment: Same issue as @anubhava answer. I've already tried similar stuff in the past before asking this question, also showing the same issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it incorrectly forward `http://ex.com/alternative-url-web222` to `http://ex.com/web2/22` ?

Comment: @TCB13 Do you have other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: You might be right the issue seems to be another .htaccess file in the `web2` dir. (Please check original question).

Comment: @TCB13 nothing there is redirecting either

Comment: This works for me partially... Just css and js are not loaded... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in order to follow the trail of htaccess redirects, you could add something like this to each of them:

```
Header add X-Remark-Rewrite "/path.to/htaccess"
```

You can inspect these in the response in the developer tools.