# url parameters without using ? and =

Tags: php, url, parameters

Sorry if the title doesn't sound clear but basically, I see multiple APIs doing it like this:

http://www.website.com/183718

Where 183718 would be the ID and then they could use that to pull results.

I want to do the same but I don't know another way besides like this:

http://www.website.com/id?=183718

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Look for `url rewriting` using for example `.htaccess` if you're on linux.

Comment: check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803615/htaccess-rewriterule-to-path-without-changing-url

Answer (score 0):

You want a mod_rewrite (placed in an .htaccess file) rule that looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+)\.html /news.php?news_id=$1
```

And this maps requests from

```
/news.php?news_id=63
```

to

```
/news/63.html
```

Another possibility is doing it with forcetype, which forces anything down a particular path to use php to eval the content. So, in your .htaccess file, put the following:

```
<Files news>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

And then the index.php can take action based on the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    // outputs '/63.html'
?>
```