# How to remove extra folder using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been playing with booked scheduler for a client but noticed that when I hit a certain part of the site it doubles up a folder in the URL and causes a 404.  I believe it should be possible to fix using .htaccess but I'm unsure where to start.

The URL should be

```
domain.com/Web/thing.php
```

but the button is loading

```
domain.com/Web/Web/thing.php
```

Is it possible to fix the broken link using .htaccess so it loads the page without the second folder?

Comment: I hope this will work for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803615/htaccess-rewriterule-to-path-without-changing-url

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Redirect /Web/Web/ /Web/
```

This will need to go in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!