# I need to change my url seo friendly with url routing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to know how I change my site url my I try url routing what is not work
my site product url is `http://www.shahilibas.in/product.php?p_id=5` and I want seo friendly url like `http://www.shahilibas.in/product.php/5`
I try this code for url routing

```
function getCurrentUri()
{
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/',      $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
    return $uri;
    echo $uri;
}
```

Comment: you will need to create a .htaccess file details on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803615/htaccess-rewriterule-to-path-without-changing-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Rewrite Rule to .htaccess file . Create new text file give it name '.htaccess' without quotes .

In Your .htaccess File Write the Code Below and Press Ctrl + s To save your File

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./serve.php?short=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code in your .htaccess file and save

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products.php?p_id=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ products.php?p_id=$1

</IfModule>
```

Then your url will be like this
http://www.shahilibas.in/5

Which is more url friendly. Showing php file in url is not good for SEO.