# Custom Profile Page like Facebook in PHP

Tags: php, profile

There are a few subjects for that to rewrite url from http://example.com/page.php?id=3 to http://example.com/username or from http://example.com/users/username to http://example.com/username.

They do that with .htaccess rewrite rule but problem is if you type example.com/username it redirects to http://example.com/page.php?id=3

But on the facebook etc. url is still same as facebook.com/username. it doesnt redirect to new url.

How do they do that?

My idea to do that creating dynamic web pages like username.html It is inefficient as memory

My .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ userinfo.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And my userinfo.php

```
<?php

require_once ("config.php");
if(isset($_GET["username"]))
{
    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM userxmeta WHERE username = :username ");
    $stmt->bindParam(":username",$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
    {
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to include your current code?

Comment: You can redirect or just rewrite. The rewrite sends the request to the server as a GET, the path to the user is still readable.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @Jasper code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer from 
[.htaccess RewriteRule to path without changing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803615/htaccess-rewriterule-to-path-without-changing-url)

```
 # Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

 #For internal pages(rewrite "/page.php?name=about us" to "AboutUs") 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&\s]+)$  
RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+)$  
RewriteRule ^(?:page\.php|)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ page.php?name=$1&r [L,QSA]
```